# Access frame in Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, tkinter

I am trying to develop a GUI with Model–view–controller architecture.
Basically I have a View

```
class View(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, controller):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "App")
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.controller = controller
        self.frames = {}
        #startPage = StartPage()
        for F in (MainPage, GraphPage):

            frame = F(container, self)

            self.frames[F] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.show_frame(MainPage, "Home")

    def show_frame(self, cont, button):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()
        self.controller.on_button_click(button)

    def main(self):
        data = self.controller.getData()
        ani = animation.FuncAnimation(f, animate, interval=250, fargs=(self.controller,data))

        
        MainPage.setLabel(MainPage, "Voltage", data)
        #self.show_frame(MainPage, "Home")

        self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.on_closing)
        self.mainloop()
```

And a MainPage class where I am trying to implement a class to modify some Label through the View class. As you can see I am trying to access the function in the View main with `MainPage.setLabel(MainPage, "Voltage", data)` but is not working.

First, I find weird that if I don't pass MainPage in the setLabel call I get this error:
-TypeError: MainPage.setLabel() missing 1 required positional argument: 'value'

Second, once I pass it like it is in the code I get this error:
-AttributeError: type object 'MainPage' has no attribute 'voltageLabel'.

Why is it not detecting voltageLabel as an attribute? WHat I am doing wrong here?

```
class MainPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, cont):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)

        self.voltageLabel = tk.StringVar()
        self.voltageLabel.set(0)
        #Voltage Label
        tk.Label(self, text='3.600V', textvariable = self.voltageLabel, 
                 bg="#F0FFFF", font=('arial', 22, 'normal')).place(x=36, y=30)
        tk.Label(self, text='Battery voltage', bg='#F0FFFF', 
                 font=('arial', 12, 'normal')).place(x=36, y=5)

    def setLabel(self, label, value):
        if label == "Voltage":
            self.voltageLabel.set(value)
```

I am trying to implement a class to modify some Label through the View class. I expect to be able to modify voltageLabel from setLabel function.

Comment: You need to use *the instance* of the class `MainPage` to call the `.setLabel()` function, not using the class.  Use `self.frames(MainPage).setLabel("Voltage", data)` instead.

Comment: Adding that I get this error:
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable

Comment: Typo: it should be `self.frames[MainPage].setLabel(...)` instead.

Comment: Yeah adding self.frames[MainPage].setLabel("Voltage", data) solves the issue. Thank you!

Comment: Which one is this tk.Label? You have both duplicated.

Comment: Why not answer your own question?